# Using TFS 2013 for Portfolio Management

Tags: tfs

1. I am planning on setting up TFS 2013 and using TFS 2013 for managing a number of projects, using the Portfolio Management features. I wanted to get a general opinion if this is a good idea - or is it quite tedious to set up and manage portfolios through TFS 2013 as compared to other PM tools available
2. In TFS 2013, I notice that the team is generally required to add in their estimates in terms of hours - original, completed and remaining. Hence, I wanted to confirm that there a way we can track the percentage of task completion within those hours (completed hours) for any tasks, and also in general for the entire project/iteration.
3. Are there any reports currently available in TFS 2013 that displays the percentage of completion across different projects?

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have edited my questions, could you please let me know if you have any information on the above?

Comment: Re 2: The online version includes automatic burn down charts per iteration, if you choose to fill in those hours, but it's also *really* easy to query TFS and report on whatever you like. It has really nice integration with Excel. Pivot and chart to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

In my -limited- experience, setting up a project in TFS isn't terrible and definitely worth the time, it does have one too many options for my current needs but that's always relative. 
For the reports perhaps [this is what you are looking for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433251.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is a well rounded tool, but It depends on your context if it is a good tool for you.
It is well integrated to microsoft tools like visual studio, it supports scrum. It supports continuous delivery. If you use other tool or your team prefer opensource tools, maybe it is not a good option. But is just an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, it is comparably tedious to set up. You need to be aware of which process template you are choosing, and the differences between them. Understanding this can save a lot of headaches in the future.

2) This depends on the process template you use. The Agile template includes tasks in hours for remaining work, completed work and original estimate fields, whilst the Scrum template has only remaining work. This will alter your reporting capabilities significantly.

3) It depends on what you mean by "Project". In TFS there exists a cascading heirarchy of containers: Team Project Collection (TPC) => Team Project => Team/Area Path. You need to really understand the relationships between these if you want to be able to report across multiple teams and projects. Primarily, you'll want to ensure that you store everything inside a single "Team Project" and use Teams and/or Area Paths to separate out your software projects into logical groupings. This will ensure the maximum amount of flexibility in reporting.

3a) As far as out-of-the-box reports, there isn't a lot. There is however a complete cube that you can point SSRS, Excel, or even better Power BI at for your reporting needs. You can also create lightweight reports from work item queries.

If you're setting up something complicated (more than 1 team across more than 1 project), I highly suggest doing some training before diving in. There are a lot of gotchya's to watch out for, and little things that can make your life easier in the future. TFS is highly customizable, which unfortunately means it can be a bit complex to set up initially in complex situations.